# May Skilling's Nested Sampling Estimate parameters in hierarchical model?

Tags: sampling, hierarchical-bayesian

May Skilling's Nested Sampling integration technique Estimate parameters in hierarchical model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

One caveat is that the number of iterations nested sampling needs is related to the information gain, which is often very high in high-dimensional hierarchical models with weakly specified priors.

In some problems where the lower levels parameters are low-dimensional (<3d), you can get away with numerically integrating them out in some cases.

Here is an nested sampling example of a small hierarchical model with 1d latent unknowns for each data point:
https://johannesbuchner.github.io/UltraNest/example-intrinsic-distribution.html